# Can not infer functional interface type in groupBy Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, collectors

I am not sure this has been answered earlier or not. Can anyone please tell me what is the problem with third `groupBy` which I've written ? Why it can not infer ?

```
class TestGroupBy
{
    enum LifeCycle {
        ANNUAL, PERENNIAL
    }

    private String name;
    private LifeCycle lifeCycle;

    TestGroupBy(String name, LifeCycle lifeCycle) {
        this.name = name;
        this.lifeCycle = lifeCycle;
    }

    LifeCycle getLifeCycle() {
        return this.lifeCycle;
    }

    static EnumMap mySupplier() {
        return new EnumMap(TestGroupBy.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<TestGroupBy> garden = new ArrayList<>();
        garden.add(new TestGroupBy("Test1", TestGroupBy.LifeCycle.ANNUAL));
        garden.add(new TestGroupBy("Test2", TestGroupBy.LifeCycle.PERENNIAL));
        garden.add(new TestGroupBy("Test4", TestGroupBy.LifeCycle.ANNUAL));
        garden.add(new TestGroupBy("Test5", TestGroupBy.LifeCycle.PERENNIAL));

        // This works
        garden.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e.getLifeCycle()));

        // This works
        garden.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                e -> e.getLifeCycle(),
                TestGroupBy::mySupplier,
                Collectors.toSet()
            ));
        // This does not work
        garden.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                e -> e.getLifeCycle(),   // Can not resolve method getLifeCycle()
                new EnumMap(TestGroupBy.class),
                Collectors.toSet()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Stop using raw types!**

This is `mySupplier` without raw types:

```
static EnumMap<LifeCycle, Set<TestGroupBy>> mySupplier() {
    return new EnumMap<>(LifeCycle.class);
}
```

The key type of an `EnumMap` must be an enum type, so you should use `LifeCycle` as the first argument. The second argument is what the collector you use at the end returns. You used `toSet` here, so I suppose you want a set of `TestGroupBy`.

That's how your supplier should look like, *with proper generic arguments* and `LifeCycle.class` as the key type of `EnumMap`!

Now, you can do this:

```
    garden.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                    e -> e.getLifeCycle(),
                    () -> new EnumMap<>(LifeCycle.class),
                    Collectors.toSet()));
```

Note that your have to add `() ->` to make it a supplier.

Answer (score 2):

There are two things wrong with code you have shown us. Firstly,you have passed wrong object with second argument of [`Collectors.groupingBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-). You have passed `EnumMap`, not `Supplier<EnumMap>`.

Secondly, you cannot instantiate `EnumMap` with `TestGroupBy.class`, because `TestGrouBy` is not an enum. In your case it should be `new EnumMap<>(LifeCycle.class)`:

```
garden.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
              e -> e.getLifeCycle(),   // Can not resolve method getLifeCycle()
              () -> new EnumMap<>(LifeCycle.class),
              Collectors.toSet()));
```

Also change implementation of `mySupplier()` method, because it's not correct. It should be:

```
static EnumMap mySupplier() {
    return new EnumMap<>(LifeCycle.class);
}
```

Comment: Can you say what I am doing wrong ? https://imgur.com/a/gBnlb

And this error occurs when I copy/paste your code.

Comment: @senerh You have another issue with `new EnumMap(TestGroupBy.class)`. It should be `new EnumMap<>(LifeCycle.class)`

Comment: Ty ! This is bcs OP did this error in his supplier method (And I copy/paste it) ! It should be `return new EnumMap(LifeCycle.class);`

Answer (score 0):

```
static EnumMap mySupplier() {
    return new EnumMap(TestGroupBy.class);
}
```

This code above will not work. Instead you should try:

```
static EnumMap<LifeCycle, Set<TestGroupBy>> mySupplier() {
    return new EnumMap<>(TestGroupBy.LifeCycle.class); // Key class is changed.
}
```

FInally, the reason for not working the below code:

```
garden.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            e -> e.getLifeCycle(),   
            new EnumMap(TestGroupBy.class),
            Collectors.toSet()));
```

is:

```
new EnumMap(TestGroupBy.class),
```

Because groupingBy accepts Supplier, not the kind of object which has been provided.

Also note that `new EnumMap(TestGroupBy.LifeCycle.class)` should have been used.